# Showing flagged content to users

Tags: commerce, flags

I have flagged contents in a block.But only admin can see the these flagged contents(contents are product variations).I want to show these contents to all authenticated users and anonymous users.Is it possible?Can you help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a permission issue, each flag you create has it's own permission settings. Have a look under `admin/people/permissions`

Comment: I have give flag/unflag permission to all users.Permission "Bypass content access control"(this for administrator) can now see this.